# Error during installation of Laravel 2.0.1

Tags: installation, macbook, troubleshooting

I'm getting this error when I try to install Laravel:

> laravel/installer v2.0.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
>   laravel/installer v2.0.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
>   Installation request for laravel/installer ^2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v2.0.0, v2.0.1].

Answer (score 0):

Thats mean you dont have zip extension 
It says that it requires zip extension

try to install zip extension

if you are using ubuntu try this command `sudo apt-get install php-zip`

and you using window try this `http://www.dlldownloader.com/php_zip-dll/`

hope its helps

Answer (score 0):

You are missing PHP zip extension.

Since you are on the MacBook, think that this would be more helpful

`brew update 
brew install php@7.3 
brew link php@7.3`

From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290566/install-ext-zip-for-mac

Just replace version number to what you need.

---